# Disable default swipe on mobile VF page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile

I'm using the jQuery moble swipe events to trigger actions on my visualforce page. However, the SF1 app is picking that up and displaying the navigation sidebar or  the notifications. Is there anyway to prevent this? I have the action limited to one element, but that doesn't seem to stop the app from picking up the event too. Thanks in advance!